# SQL trailing spaces removal to fit certain length

Tags: sql, padding, trailing

I have a SQL column of Employee City and the file output requires 40 characters in length. The system retrieves a value that is 58 characters.

This city value can change in length (Chicago, Warrenville), but will always need to be 40 characters in the end with spaces after the city value. I would like to use padding because trimming the spaces would be different each time.

Comment: and which database are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: what does "the system retrieves a value that is 58 characters" mean?